# Hibernate generates duplicate ids

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a problem with the hibernate id generation. I want to persist a mock ProcessStartParameter object with 3 schedules (expectedSchedule, lowerBoundSchedule and upperBoundSchedule) and 15 test ScheduleEntry objects per schedule in a MySQL database. When I try to persist them this error occurs:

```
ERROR: HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '14' for key 'PRIMARY'], SQL: update testDb.scheduleEntries set scheduleId=?, id=? where id=?
```

I've tried to persist the schedules one after the other but the same error occured.

Do you have a idea what's wrong or what I've to change?

ProcessStartParameter.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.ProcessStartParameter" table="processStartParameters">
        
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"></generator>  
        </id>
        <many-to-one cascade="all"  name="processCall" unique="true" not-null="true" column="processCallId" class="de.test.ProcessCall" fetch="join" lazy="false" ></many-to-one>
        <many-to-one cascade="delete, lock, delete-orphan, save-update, merge" name="upperBoundSchedule" unique="true" not-null="false" column="upperBoundScheduleId" class="de.test.Schedule" lazy="false"></many-to-one>
        <many-to-one cascade="delete, lock, delete-orphan, save-update, merge" name="lowerBoundSchedule" unique="true" not-null="false" column="lowerBoundScheduleId" class="de.test.Schedule" lazy="false"></many-to-one>
        <many-to-one cascade="delete, lock, delete-orphan, save-update, merge" name="expectedSchedule" unique="true" not-null="false" column="expectedScheduleId" class="de.test.Schedule" lazy="false"></many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Schedule.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.Schedule" table="schedules">
        
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="description" />
        </property>
        <list name="scheduleEntries" cascade="all" >
            <key column="scheduleId"></key>
            <list-index column="id"></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="de.test.ScheduleEntry" />
        </list>
     </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

ScheduleEntry.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.ScheduleEntry" table="scheduleEntries">
        
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"></generator>  
        </id>
        <property name="timeStamp" type="java.time.Instant">
            <column name="timeStamp" />
        </property>
        <property name="energy_kW" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="energy_kW" />
        </property>
        <property name="energyAmount_kWh" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="energyAmount_kWh" />
        </property>
     </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The databaseHandler to generate mock objects and to persist them

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import de.test.ProcessStartParameter;
import de.test.Schedule;
import de.test.ScheduleEntry;

/**
 * The Class DatabaseHandler.
 */
public class DatabaseHandler {

    /** The session. */
    private Session session;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new database handler.
     */
    public DatabaseHandler() {}

    /**
     * Returns the current session instance.
     * 
     * @return the session
     */
    public Session getSession() {
        if (session == null) {
            session = DatabaseSessionFactoryHandler.getNewDatabaseSession();
        }
        return session;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current session instance.
     * 
     * @param session the new session
     */
    public void setSession(Session session) {
        if (this.session != null) {
            if (session == null) {
                this.session.close();
            } else {
                if (this.session != session) {
                    this.session.close();
                }
            }
        }
        this.session = session;
    }

    /**
     * Disposes this database handler by closing the database session.
     */
    public void dispose() {
        this.setSession(null);
    }
        /**
     * Generate mock schedule.
     *
     * @param description the description
     * @param startAt     the start at
     * @param timeStep    the time step
     * @param noOfEntries the no of entries
     * @param energyMin   the energy min
     * @param energyMax   the energy max
     * @param stepWidth   the step width
     * @return the schedule
     */
    public Schedule generateMockSchedule(String description, LocalDateTime startAt, Duration timeStep, int noOfEntries, double energyMin,
            double energyMax, double stepWidth) {
        Schedule mockSchedule = new Schedule();
        mockSchedule.setDescription(description);
        mockSchedule.setScheduleEntries((ArrayList<ScheduleEntry>) this.generateScheduleEntries(startAt, timeStep, noOfEntries, energyMin, energyMax,
                stepWidth, mockSchedule));
        return mockSchedule;

    }

    /**
     * Generate schedule entries.
     *
     * @param startAt     the start at
     * @param timeStep    the time step
     * @param noOfEntries the no of entries
     * @param energyMin   the energy min
     * @param energyMax   the energy max
     * @param stepWidth   the step width
     * @param schedule    the schedule
     * @return the list
     */
    public List<ScheduleEntry> generateScheduleEntries(LocalDateTime startAt, Duration timeStep, int noOfEntries, double energyMin, double energyMax,
            double stepWidth, Schedule schedule) {
        ArrayList<ScheduleEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<ScheduleEntry>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        double energy = energyMin + (int) (Math.random() * ((energyMax - energyMin)));
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfEntries; i++) {
            ScheduleEntry mockEntry = new ScheduleEntry();
            if (energy + stepWidth > energyMax) {
                energy -= stepWidth;
            } else if (energy - stepWidth < energyMin) {
                energy += stepWidth;
            } else {
                if (rand.nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
                    energy += stepWidth;
                } else {
                    energy -= stepWidth;
                }

            }
            double energyAmount = (energy * timeStep.getSeconds()) / (60 * 60);
            mockEntry.setEnergy_kW(energy);
            mockEntry.setEnergyAmount_kWh(energyAmount);
            mockEntry.setTimeStamp(startAt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
            mockEntry.setSchedule(schedule);
            startAt.plusSeconds(timeStep.getSeconds());
            entryList.add(mockEntry);
        }
        return entryList;
    }
    
    public Schedule persistSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
        Session session = this.getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(schedule);
        transaction.commit();
        return schedule;
    }
}
```

The action method to persist a generated mock object

```java
    public void action() {
                DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
                Schedule mockSchedule = dbHandler.generateMockSchedule("expectedSchedule", LocalDateTime.now(), Duration.ofMinutes(15), 15, 0.0,
                25.0, 0.75);
                dbHandler.persistSchedule(mockSchedule);
    }
```

Comment: You are going to have to show the code interacting with Hibernate at a bare minimum for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: @SteveEbersole thank you for the advice :). I hope the added code makes it clearer

Comment: No idea.  That all looks fine.  If you still think its a problem other than your code, submit a issue in Hibernate Jira.  However, please first distill this into a mcve/mwe test case.  This serves 2 purposes - (1) it is often the case that boiling this down to the bare minimum highlights the error in your code and (2) it makes it easier for us to debug the issue